# Loading multiple Stripe Checkout Buttons with form action pages

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

So let's say you have this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/service1/2/3.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL HERE"><br>
<input type="button" id="service1" value="Service 1">
<input type="button" id="service2" value="Service 2">
<input type="hidden" id="service3" name="Service 3" />
</form>
```

Then this is the script for stripe:

```
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
data-amount="1000"
data-name="Services"
data-description="MyServices"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-locale="auto"
data-currency="cad"
data-zip-code="true"
data-label = "PAY WITH CARD - $10 CAD">
</script>
```

If they select option 1, they should be charged $10 and taken to the following page: service1.php

If they select option 2, they should be charged $20 and taken to the following page:
service2.php

.php pages hold a script which the service script takes place.

How would i do that!

Be easy on me, i can't JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Separate Stripe Checkout Forms on One Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868734/two-separate-stripe-checkout-forms-on-one-page)

Comment: It's not a duplicate; the other one uses the custom JavaScript implementation, whereas this one specifically calls for no JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

I think in this case you'll want 2 (or 3) separate `<form>` tags, each of which point to the appropriate PHP script in their `action`, and each with their own Checkout `<script>` tag.

Comment: Yes, however they will each have to have a seperate text field for the email:
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL HERE"><br>

Comment: Just let Checkout collect that, since it's going to anyways.

Comment: That includes the same `checkout.js` script multiple times. Not good.

Comment: Given they don't want to use JavaScript, this is the right answer.  Including checkout.js in this way doesn't just load the checkout JavaScript, it also runs it to load up there button, etc - and to do that twice (without writing some JavaScript), you need to include it twice.